# How to set setContentView(); to GONE

Tags: java, android, visibility

I have my main layout which is, setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail),

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
```

how do i set the visibility of my layout as GONE within the below code

```
   if (extras.get("NAME").equals("Blog")) {
        Intent blog = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
        blog.putExtra("URL", "url");
        blog.putExtra("filename", "Blog");
        startActivity(blog);

  // I want to Perform the operation here

        }
```

Comment: Unable to get what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i think you are talking about intent put extra and get extra. go to ReportActivity.class and use 

String URL=getIntent().getExtras().getString("URL");
and do as per your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think actually you are trying to close the current activity while opening a new one.

You can do it as below, no need to hide the current activity.

```
 Intent blog = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
 blog .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 blog.putExtra("URL", "url");
 blog.putExtra("filename", "Blog");
 startActivity(blog);
 finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do your operation like below.

```
if (extras.get("NAME").equals("Blog")) {
    Intent blog = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
    blog.putExtra("URL", "url");
    blog.putExtra("filename", "Blog");
    startActivity(blog);

    // I want to Perform the operation here...

    //Get the root view and hide...

    findViewById(android.R.id.content).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't make any sense at all since he will be navigating to ReportActivity.
This is redundant!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

1.

```
 View view=findViewById(android.R.id.content)
 view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

2.

```
View view= getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

3.

```
final  View view= = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
            .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/root_view" >

   //...


</LinearLayout>

View view=findViewById(android.R.id.root_view)
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: why are you using findViewById? He set an layout with R.layout and not R.id., You cant remove an layout with r.id

Answer (score 0):

set you content view in else part

```
   if (extras.get("NAME").equals("Blog")) {
    Intent blog = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, ReportActivity.class);
    blog.putExtra("URL", "url");
    blog.putExtra("filename", "Blog");
    startActivity(blog);

    }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    }
```